# Why does Regex Group is being returned?

Tags: regex

I was thinking...

when im writing (js)

```
var t="1234ABC4321".match(/.*(ABC).*/)
```

it returns :

```
["1234ABC4321", "ABC"]
```

I can replace the `, "ABC"]` part  by `(?:...)`

However, Groups are for : `backreference` , so i can reference them by `\1` later....

question :

why does "ABC" is returned as a part of the matches ? 
if he needs it for himself for later back reference  , `fine` ! but **dont** keep it in my collection !

is there any logic ( i'm sure there is) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is that the match() method checks if your string matches the regexp. If it does it returns you the part of the string that matches the regexp. If you specify grouping with () it will return the groups as well.

If your are looking to remove ABC from your string use:

```
var t="1234ABC4321".replace(/ABC/, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I am understanding your question but when grouping, the first group you get is the whole string which is matched by the regular expression. If you do not want to get a secondary group (the `ABC`), remove the brackets (`(` and `)`) since these denote groups in regular expressions, so this regex: `/.*ABC.*/` should yield you 1 group being `1234ABC4321`.